# Automating ClickOnce deployment with security (certificates, etc.) such that client installs the application without any prompt

Tags: .net, security, deployment, clickonce, certificate

I just read *[Configuring ClickOnce Trusted Publishers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx)* and got it running at another computer on network. I deployed the application on network itself (that is, `\\\abc\something`).

Though I could not find certmgr.exe as part of Windows core component, as the article says (..so you will need to use the certificate management console (certmgr.exe) included in Windows..), I instead found it at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin". It worked fine, but did I miss something? I mean, what if the user did not have Visual Studio installed?

Now, I had to *explicitly* go and get this thing done (that is, importing the certificate using certmgr.exe) on the user/client's computer on the network. Is there a way to *automate* it? Where I do nothing explicitly and when the user clicks `setup.exe` in the deployed application on the network (`\\\abc\something`), he/she can install the same without getting security-based prompts.

I checked out BOOTSTRAP, but I could not exactly understand how to use it, HERE? I thought of pasting the certificate at its appropriate location (thought that importing the certificate using `certmgr.exe` pastes it somewhere on the disk? In some "personal" directory)?

In gist, I want to automate the process where user can install the application from network (`\\\abc\something`) without security/trust prompts. And I as a developer need 
not *explicitly* import the certificate in his/her/user/client's computer.

Answer (score 1):

CERTMGR is an MMC snapin, not an EXE. Run it as `CERTMGR.MSC`.

Alternatively, you can use `CERTUTIL.EXE` from the command line, which is available in `C:\Windows\System32` on recent versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

> CERTMGR is an MMC snapin, not an EXE

No, these are in fact two (slightly) different tools.

On Windows 7 Professional, `certmgr.msc` is installed by default into `System32`. It is a pure GUI [MMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Management_Console) and cannot be scripted.

`certmgr.exe` can be used on the command line and is provided with the [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279) which must be downloaded and installed separately. But I suppose the .exe would work on any Windows 7 machine, even without the other SDK tools installed.