# How to deploy Outlook 2013 add-in with simplest installation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsto, clickonce, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I am currently using ClickOnce to deploy the simple Outlook 2013 Add-in I developed.

It seems like it will generate a folder with 3 files inside. Users have to open the folder and run the setup.exe file, the popup windows will require users to click "install" to finish the installation steps.

Since I am fairly new to .Net framework, and my team asks me to find out a better solution when installing the add-in that users only need to click one file and get everything set up. Because we hope the users can only go through very simple process to set up the add-in.

Do you think is there any way that I can deploy my add-in to have only one file generated and users can click that to install without any windows pop up?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All possible options for deploying Office add-ins are described in the [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) section in MSDN.

Note, you can call VSTOInstaller directly with the /i /s flags for a silent installation. See [ClickOnce and Silent mode installation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/bbbb43b2-16af-491d-a65e-0502b76ab0c4/clickonce-and-silent-mode-installation) and [How to install ClickOnce app without prompting the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732040/how-to-install-clickonce-app-without-prompting-the-user) for more information.

In case MSI installer you are able to use the `/quiet` or `/qn` options with `msiexec` to perform a silent install. Read more about that in [Silent installation of a MSI package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package).

Comment: Thanks Mate. Do you know is there any way to publish the add-in into single one file instead of a folder with both setup.exe and xxxx.vsto? Can clickonce achieve that? Since I need to send the installer to a lot of customers via email, it would be hard for all of them to understand how to download the zip file, unzip it and choose the right file to run.