# Deploy clickonce application using group policy

Tags: .net, clickonce

I want to know if it is possible to deploy ClickOnce application using group policy.

If yes, how?

I know that ClickOnce applications are installed on per-user basis and not for everyone.

But is there any way we can install for all users?

Comment: See if [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23593726/109702) is suitable for you.