# Click to Run Silent Install

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems, windows-installer

I have a click to run web installer that I have been trying to install silently through PowerShell. Some things I have tried was "Start-process", running the .application file directly but also running the web installer directly from the site using PS. I am still being prompted to open the file through the browser and then run the installer manually. The goal is to have the web installer run silently and to force the install without user input. I have also checked and there are not .exe or .msi files for this and apparently the only way to have this app installed is through this click to run file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That depends on the application being installed. You'll have to look at the website and see if there are any command line arguments for use to install using a shell.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! There aren't any shell arguments so I had a thought - what if I place the web installer link within another file and call the file containing the app link and have it run silently. Would that work?

Comment: Assuming that this is a Click Once application installation, it is very difficult to run completely silently because that's not the way Click Once works. Every time it runs it checks for new versions i.e. this means launching a browser and going to the hosting location to compare versions. You can make it easier, by trusting the Signing Certificate, but it will still launch the browser. If you are totally committed to a silent install, I would take a look at this entrepreneurial answer: [How to install ClickOnce app without prompting the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028149/2150063)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try that link. I appreciate it!